# Merge request approval invalidates after new push

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-api, merge-request

In gitlab is there a setting that affects if an approval for an MR is invalidated after a new commit is pushed? I have seen that in some setups a new commit invalidates the approval but in others not so wondering what is the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Merge request approval settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/settings.html) including "Remove all approvals when commits are added to the source branch" are configurable per project. These settings also require a Premium subscription.

So, you may experience differences based on how the project is configured or the subscription level of the customer/instance.

Answer (score 0):

The setting "[Remove all approvals when commits are added to the source branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/settings.html)" is still for Premium or Ultimate, but [GitLab 16.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/01/18/gitlab-16-8-released/#smarter-approval-resets-with-patch-id-support) (January 2024) adds (for all editions):

> ### Smarter approval resets with `patch-id` support
>
> To ensure all changes are reviewed and approved, it’s common to remove all approvals when new commits are added to a merge request. However, rebases also unnecessarily invalidated existing approvals, even if the rebase introduced no new changes, requiring authors to seek re-approval.
>
> Merge request approvals now align to a [`git-patch-id`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id). It’s a reasonably stable and reasonably unique identifier that enables smarter decisions about resetting approvals. By comparing the `patch-id` before and after the rebase, we can determine if new changes were introduced that should reset approvals and require a review.
>
> If you have feedback about your experiences with resets now, let us know in [issue #435870](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/435870).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/settings.html#remove-all-approvals-when-commits-are-added-to-the-source-branch) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/10249).